# Handle auto scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have an autoscroll usercontrol, I need to handle the scroll event when I focus a control and it centers automatically.

I have tried the Scroll event but it seems it doesn't work when the scroll is made by the usercontrol itself

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to put a control like a TextBox in the middle of the container when it gets focus?  Is this WinForms, I assume?

Comment: It's WinForms, I try to focus on the textbox without change the scroll

Comment: So you want no auto-scrolling at all?

Comment: I don't want scroll by focus, I just need scroll by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UserControl, try overriding the ScrollToControl function:

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
  return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
}
```